# Query children and its children until there are no children simplified

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

Let's say we have an entity with the following properties:

```
public class Foo    
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

A child is any Foo that has a non-null ParentId. There can be several levels of parent/child relationships, up to 5 at this point.

*Is there a simple LINQ way or general methodology to begin with a Foo and get all of its children, and its children's children, and it's children's children's children, etc?*

Currently, I'm looping through each child of the beginning parent, then looping again to get all of that child's children, etc. This is tedious and doesn't appear to be the correct way of accomplishing what I want.

Comment: Do you have some lookup table here to get children? It sounds like you want a given "parent" `Foo` and get its children, but there's no mechanism to get children. The data model you have here allows us to crawl _up_ the tree to parents, but not traverse _down_ it.

Comment: I just have the one table, Foo. Given a Foo object, to get it's children, I query for all Foo's with ParentId = x. Then, for each of those children, I query for ParentId = the ID of the child of the previous parent, etc. What do I need to change to include a mechanism that allows me to simplify the process of getting all children and its children?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that this is using Entity Framework.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to maintain a string property that represents a place in the hierarchy.  For example, if the value was "/99/42" then you know the item belongs to parent 42 which belongs to 99.  The reason this is nice is because then you can flatten out the whole collection of Foos and just query that field for those beginning with "/99" and you'll get the entire branch of the hierarchy.  So your class would look like this:

```
public class Foo    
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; } //eg: /99/42
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 I do like this. I'm wondering if there is a built-in method or assortment of methods to accomplish this though.

Comment: I don't know of anything built-in.  It's not too difficult to implement though.  Not much harder to maintain than the ParentId thing you're already doing.  Let me know if you come up with something simpler though.

Comment: Rather than having all of the IDs stuck together in a string that needs to be parsed, it would be preferable to just have an `IEnumerable<int>` (or some specific collection) with all of the IDs.  Then you don't need to worry about parsing logic.

Comment: @Josh Well, most tree structures have a reference to their children, and may or may not have a reference to their parent.  That's the standard solution.

Comment: @Servy What do you mean by reference to their children? Isn't the ParentId the reference to the parent? So, to get all children, you'd query all Foos with that parentId?

Comment: @Josh The standard implementation of a tree is not to start by defining the parents and finding the children based on that info, but to start by defining the children of each node as it's definition.

Comment: @Servy I'm still confused here. How would you re-define what I have then? I thought it was standard to have at least those properties in the DB/Entity to relate them.

Comment: @Josh Just swinging back around here.  I don't know that my answer is a standard solution, but I've seen it in other places.  For example, this is how it's done in Orchard CMS's Taxonomy module. http://orchardtaxonomies.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Models/TermPart.cs

Comment: I ended up writing a recursive method that will traverse the tree to the root (parent), then traverse back up the tree to get all of its children.

Answer (score 1):

So if *all* you have is one `Foo` object then no, you cannot get all of it's descendants.  At the very least, you'd need to have a sequence of *all* `Foo` objects as well in order to find the nodes that have that one object as a parent, since your `Foo` object doesn't already have a reference to it's children.  If you *do* have that sequence, then it's not particularly hard.

You can use `ToLookup` on the sequence of all foos to create a lookup of ID to all children of that ID value:

```
var allFoos = new List<Foo>();

var childrenLookup = allFoos.ToLookup(foo => foo.ParentId);
```

To get a sequence of all descendants for a particular child you now have simple tree traversal:

```
public static IEnumerable<Foo> Descendants(Foo foo, ILookup<int?, Foo> childrenLookup)
{
    var stack = new Stack<Foo>();
    stack.Push(foo);

    while (stack.Any())
    {
        var next = stack.Pop();
        yield return next;

        foreach (var child in childrenLookup[next.Id])
            stack.Push(child);
    }
}
```